# Do I still need to load word2vec model at model testing?

Tags: machine-learning, word2vec

This may sound like a naive question, but i am quite new on this. Let's say I use the Google pre-trained word2vector model (https://github.com/dav/word2vec) to train a classification model. I save my classification model. Now I load back the classification model into memory for testing new instances. Do I need to load the Google word2vector model again? Or is it only used for training my model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how your corpuses and test examples are structured and pre-processed.

You are probably using the pre-trained word-vectors to turn text into numerical features. At first, text examples are vectorized to train the classifier. Later, other (test/production) text examples will be vectorized in the same, and presented to get the classifier to get its judgements.

So you will need to use the same text-to-vectors process for test/production text examples as was used during training. Perhaps you've done that in a separate earlier bulk step, in which case you already have the features in the vector form the classifier uses. But often your classifier pipeline will itself take raw text, and vectorize it – in which case it will need the same pre-trained (word)->(vector) mappings available at test time as were available during training.